# How to get to the formula of this joint probability

Tags: independence, integral

In Bishops book, "Statistical Pattern Recognition", in Chapter 8 about Graphical models he introduces the following 3-node graph:

[image: 3-node graph]

The goal is to investigate the independence properties of node $a$ and $b$. The joint distribution is simply:

$p(a,b,c) = p(a)  p(c|a)  p(b|c)$

Further, he investigates the case, that no variable is observed. Thus, to get the joint probability $p(a,b)$, we must marginalize over $c$:

$p(a,b) = \int_{c}^{} p(a)  p(c|a)  p(b|c) \,dc  = p(a)p(b|a)$.

I got no clue how I achieve the final result. I know, that we can write

$\int_{c}^{} p(a)  p(c|a)  p(b|c) \,dc = p(a) \int_{c}^{} p(c|a)  p(b|c) \,dc $

But I lack some rules of integral calculation I suppose. I know that in general, marginalizing over $c$ will eventually throw out $c$, for example, I think that:

$\int_{c}^{} p(c|b)  \,dc  = p(b)$

But I do not know if this rule can be applied in my case. I appreciate any hints for that very trivial question!

Comment: Is the breakdown implied by that graphic not p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)?

Comment: my bad, sorry. I corrected it

Comment: now we see that p(a) is constant in the integral, and can be pulled out. The next step is the trickiest: we now have int p(c|a) p(b|c) dc. The trick is to introduce the unnecessary dependence notation p(b|c,a) = p(b|c). Then we have int p(c|a) p(b|c,a) dc, and we can use the rule int p(c|b)dc = p(b) together with a little bit of thought.

Comment: just be sure , int p(b|a,c) dc is not the same as p(b|a), right?

Comment: that's correct, it's rather that p(b|a,c)=p(b|a) (this is from the graphical model).

Comment: I see, but in general, it holds that int p(c|x1, ... xN) dc = p(x1, ... , xN) ? Do have by any chance a source for sort of an illustration for this. I would like to further study that

Comment: Almost, but rather it's that $\int p(c,x1,...,XN) dc = p(x1, ..., xN)$, or put another way, since $p(c,x1,...,xN) = p(c)p(c|x1,...,xN)$, that $\int p(c)p(c|x1,...,XN) dc = p(x1, ..., xN)$. This is just the process of marginalization of the variable c. Intuitively, the new probability distribution is just the integral/sum of the joint distribution when c is in a given state weighted by how likely c is to be in that state to begin with.

Comment: $p(c, x_1, ..., x_N) = p(c)p(c|x_1, ..., x_N)$, how do you get to this equivalence transformation? Thinking about to the Product Rule $p(a,b) = p(a|b)p(b) = p(b|a)p(a)$, this seems rather new to me.